# Getting 0s for t-test and KS test pvalues when creating balance table with ebal

Tags: r, matching

I'm trying to create a balance table using this code:

```
library(ebal)
library(matching)
mout <- MatchBalance(DV ~ someIVs, data=dataset)
balance.test <- baltest.collect(matchbal.out=mout, var.names=colnames(dataset)[-c(unnecessary_variables)], after=FALSE)
balance.test

bal.output <- round(balance.test[,c("mean.Tr","mean.Co","T pval","KS pval")],2)
stargazer(bal.output,title = "Balance Test on Olken Data", type = "text")
```

Now I have used this code for other data and it worked fine. This time, however, I receive meaningful "mean.Tr" (mean for treatment) and "mean.Co" (mean for control) but the p-values for the t-test and the KS-test are reported as 0s. Some of the KS test p-values are reported as NAs or (as stargazer outputs them) as blank cells.

The output table looks something like this:

```
Balance Test

         mean.Tr   mean.Co   T pval KS pval

IV1      25.820     34.850       0       0   
IV2      10.350     12.120       0       0   
IV3      0.840      0.250        0           
IV4      0.060      0.030        0.130         
IV5      0.190      0.870        0           
IV6      2,095.570  19,428.750   0       0   
IV7      1,532.060  19,063.340   0       0   
IV8      0.710      0.090        0           
IV8      0.600      0.100        0
```

I know that it would be easiest to upload some sample data but unfortunately, I cannot replicate this result with fabricated data. My question is, therefore, what in my data (or my code) might cause this behavior?

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: matching and ebal

Answer (score 1):

So after lots of googling I found that the 0s in my balance test are simply a result of extremely low p-values. The blanks/NAs are a result of the KS test not working for dummy variables (I guess I should have made clear that the blanks only show up for dummy variables).

Unfortunately, I still have not understood why the KS test does not yield meaningful p-values for binary variables. Binary variables also have a distribution, don't they? Why can't the KS test measure if the distribution of one binary variable matches that of another binary variable?

Even though I have answered my own question, I would still appreciate an answer to this question.

Comment: The KS statistic for a binary variable is equal to the difference in proportions. The KS test isn't reported because the t-test p-value provides exactly the same information. Also you don't use `ebal` anywhere in your code so you can omit that as it could be a red herring for other errors you might face.